# Cloud function crashes immediately after triggering

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm trying to trigger a cloud function to create a new dataproc cluster in the event of pub/sub topic which gets message whenever any dataproc cluster creation gets failed with status code of numeric digit apart from zero(status_code!=0) in cloud logging (dataproc activity log).

I have written a python code for the above scenario but this cloud function crashes immediately after triggering by pub/sub.

What is wrong in my code and what needs to be modified based on the above scenario to execute successfully.

```py
import base64
import json

import googleapiclient.discovery
from google.cloud import dataproc_v1 as dataproc

def dataproc_workflow(event, context):
    """
    Triggered by a Cloud Pub/Sub message containing a Dataproc status code != 0
    audit activity Stackdriver log message
    """
    pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
    msg_json = json.loads(pubsub_message)
    proto_payload = msg_json['protoPayload']
    resource_name = proto_payload['resourceName']
    email = proto_payload['authenticationInfo']['principalEmail']
    client = dataproc.ClusterControllerClient()
    create_cluster(client, project_id, zone, region, cluster_name)
    print(f"Cluster created: {cluster_name}.")

def create_cluster(client, project_id, zone, region, cluster_name):
    print('Creating cluster...')
    cluster_data = {
        'project_id': *********************,
        'cluster_name': simple,
        'region' : ******************,
        'config': {
            'config_bucket': ************,
    'gce_cluster_config': {
      'zone_uri': ********************,
      'subnetwork_uri': ********************,
      'internal_ip_only': true,
      'service_account_scopes': [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
      ],
      'tags': [
        'dataproc-rule',
              ]
    },
            'master_config': {
                'num_instances': 1,
                'machine_type_uri': 'n1-standard-1'
            },
            'worker_config': {
                'num_instances': 2,
                'machine_type_uri': 'n1-standard-1'
                      }
        }     
    }
    response = client.create_cluster(project_id, region, cluster_data)
    result = response.result()
    print("After cluster create")
    
    return result
```

Comment: Can you include a stack trace or exception message?

Comment: I couldn't find any traces in stackdriver trace but in log I could see  "Function execution took 325 ms, finished with status: 'crash'"   .. Code snippet respective to responding to pub/sub is correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telling from the snippet, seems all Dataproc cluster configs are hardcoded? e.g. project_id, region, etc., instead of reading from method arguments. Also the arguments passed in `create_cluster(client, project_id, zone, region, cluster_name)` doesn't appear to be defined anywhere which will definitely crash your program whenever the workflow gets triggered.

If this is not the issue and those variables are neglected intentionally then please attach your full stacktrace.

Comment: Yes , I just neglected intentionally ,, I assume the problem is with capturing & responding to pub/sub event in code .